# Stop scroll menu under some width

Tags: jquery, css, menu, responsive-design, scroll

So, I've a menu that scroll with my site when certain point.
But also I want stopt it when my site has 768px width.

I try this way

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(window).width() < 760)
     {
        $('#menu').css({'position' : 'absolute'});
     }
 });
```

And that way either:

```
$(function() {
if ( $(window).width() < 760) {     
  $('#menu').css({'position' : 'relative'});
}
});
```

Fail in both attempts. But making improvements any of them serves?

Maybe this help. This is the code that turn my menu scroll.

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function()
{
var topo = $('#topo').height(); // altura do topo
var rodape = $('#rodape').height(); // altura do rodape
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // qto foi rolado a barra
var tamPagina = $(document).height(); // altura da p?gina

if(scrollTop > topo){
  $('#menu').css({'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : '0'});
}else{
  $('#menu').css({'position' : 'relative', 'margin-top' : 0});
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var something = $('.class').offset();
something = something.top;  

$(function() {
  if ( $(window).width() < 760 || $(window).scrollTop() >= something) {     
    $('#menu').css({'position' : 'fixed'});
  }
});
```

Check this out as an example on how to make a sticky nav, which you are asking.
http://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD

Also, || = or in if conditionary.

Comment: Tks. But I'm a beginner. I saw your example on Codepen, but in this example, like in my page, this menu don't stop in your original position when the width under < 760. This is my intention. I tried use your code, but I need create .class attribute or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a somewhat 'responsive' design, use [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and 'breakpoints' - you are doing too much work with jquery here..

- In this instance, you identified your breakpoint as '768px-width'.
- so instead of using jquery to find the window width, use css like so

```
#menu{
     height:10px;         // first define your menu;
    }

    @media (max-width: 769px) {
      #menu {
        position: fixed;     // header does not move at this width
        // then you can add a media query for that size, notice i used 769px, so this includes 768px and below;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I knew that and I tried, but the case is, I think the that JQuery work doesn't matter css class, because it put some attributes independently of resolution.